# Why can't we use relationship segue and action segue (push) for one interface controller in Apple watch storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, apple-watch

Problem:
The cancel controller will not be show after the test button is tapped if both "relationship segue" and "action segue" (push) are connected

[image]

Weird behavior:
The cancel controller will show after the test button is tapped only if "action segue" (push) is connected. But not the "relationship segue".

[image]

Question:
Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't describe that much but please note that hierarchical and page-based navigation are mutually exclusive so you can't use both.

"For WatchKit apps with more than one screen of content, you must choose a technique for navigating between those screens. WatchKit apps support two navigation styles, which are mutually exclusive."

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html

Comment: This limitation doesn't make sense... I would like to have a page base navigation and also a hierarchical one... And for the hierarchical one, I need to pop back to root view controller from the 3rd/4th view.. For now I can use a modal segue together with a page base navigation. But how can I pop back to root view controller with modal segue?

Comment: It does make sense because you are only supposed to use one of those approaches and you can also use modal pages. Once you open a modal screen, there is a cancel button (on the title of the screen) to close it and go back. You can open a page based structure from a main screen and the closing those page based screens from any of them and go back to the main screen.

Comment: Thx jastrada, you mentioned that "Once you open a modal screen, there is a cancel button (on the title of the screen) to close it and go back.". What if I have opened 2 modal view and want to go back to the root? Do I need to press "cancel" twice?

Comment: Didn't try that but I think you will need to press cancel twice

Comment: Aiks... It's not very elegant to do that... Will post another question soon.

Comment: You are right, it is not. In my current project I have to do something similar to that (open 2 modals and go back to root). Please let me know when you post the question so I get noticed.

Comment: it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739473/how-to-pop-back-to-root-view-from-a-2nd-view?noredirect=1#comment45763835_28739473 Thanks!